# What language is used in the Fire Emblem Awakening soundtrack?

Tags: fire-emblem-awakening

I really enjoy listening the to Fire Emblem Awakening soundtrack. However, it is difficult for me to tell what language the lyrics are in. To me, it sounds Latin, but I can't be positive. From what I've researched, some people say it's Latin, but they don't seem too sure about this. There doesn't seem to be an answer based off of official facts. Does anyone know the language the lyrics are in?

For anyone that hasn't heard the soundtrack, [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IgT0BTN2aOI) is a link to one of the songs from the soundtrack that contains lyrics.

Comment: I don't know about Awakening in particular, but in the past it's been Japanese spoken backwards. It might be the same for Awakening, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Why did this get a down vote? I think it's pretty clear and it's about video games. The help center doesn't say anything against these kind of questions from what I remember...

Comment: I have no idea, actually. People tend to downvote for all kinds of reasons.

Comment: @Nolonar Hm... Thanks for your comment about the other Fire Emblem songs. That's pretty interesting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This thread](http://serenesforest.net/forums/index.php?showtopic=49644) on the Serenes Forest forums goes into an attempt to translate the lyrics in one of the songs. Serenes Forest is a Fire Emblem fansite, considered a strong source of information for many Fire Emblem fans. In addition, at least two users who claim to be studied in Latin voiced their opinions in the thread. According to the people there, **it seems to be Latin, but possibly poorly-written Latin**, which could make sense if it was translated either directly from Japanese to Latin or with English in the middle.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Mike! You answer is the best I've seen after researching. If there is not a better answer within the next day, you will receive the bounty.